# Load combo box item based on time difference

Tags: powershell

Below is my GUI where i am selecting date (from and to) and a interval time.

[image]

right now the **sample Interval** combo box have default values like below

```
$cmb_InterVal                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$cmb_InterVal.width              = 212
$cmb_InterVal.height             = 20
$cmb_InterVal.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(139,178)
$cmb_InterVal.Font               = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',8)
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("5 min")
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("15 min")
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("30 min")
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("60 min")
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("1 day")
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("15 days")
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("30 days")
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("365 days")
```

but now based on the time from and to difference have to display the values in combo box.

e.g. if the from and to date difference is 30 days or more than, combox box should load all other values apart from 5min and 15 min like below

```
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("30 min")
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("60 min")
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("1 day")
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("15 days")
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("30 days")
                                   $cmb_InterVal.Items.add("365 days")
```

if the time is less than 30, then all the values should be visible.

Need some idea on how to do this.

Comment: You are not showing enough of what you are doing (show the code for the from), or providing a clear explanation of your use case, well at least for me, but I'm old and well, you know.   ;-}  Yet, If I guess at this, you are not setting a timespan, to get the array that meets that spec, that should be in the interval dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

From the small piece of code you show us, there is no telling how you named the different controls, so in the code below, I'm inventing my own names for these:

In the Click event handler of the `Generate` button, you need to create real DateTime objects from the Text properties of the controls. To me, they look like a DateTimePicker control for the date part and a NumericUpDown control for the time part.

Once you have these DateTime objects, you can simply subtract one from the other to obtain a TimeSpan object.

Try:

```
$generateButton.Add_Click({
    # get the date from the TimeFrom DateTimePicker control and the time from the UpDown control
    $dateFrom = [datetime]::ParseExact(('{0} {1}' -f $datePickerFrom.Text, $timeUpDownFrom.Text), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm', $null)
    # same for the TimeTo
    $dateTo = [datetime]::ParseExact(('{0} {1}' -f $datePickerTo.Text, $timeUpDownTo.Text), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm', $null)
    # get the total number of minutes between the two dates
    $minutes = [math]::Abs(($dateTo - $dateFrom).TotalMinutes)

    $cmb_InterVal.Items.Clear()
    if ($minutes -lt 30) {
        $cmb_InterVal.Items.Add("5 min")
        $cmb_InterVal.Items.Add("15 min")
    }
    # add the rest of the items to the combobox
    '30 min', '60 min', '1 day', '15 days', '30 days', '365 days' | ForEach-Object {
        $cmb_InterVal.Items.Add($_)
    }
})
```

Comment: The lesson here is the more code and information about the problem that you provide, the easier it is for us to help.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks for your answer. As you mentioned the code written in the button click. i need to do that on the date change. so once i select the dates, code will get the difference between them and based on that the values will be displayed. which event to use for that in datetimepicker.

Comment: @EmptyCoder OK, so in that case put the code inside the DatePicker's `SelectedDateChanged` event instead of the button `Click`